# Is std::map allowed to re-balance after read-only operations (like a Splay tree)

Tags: c++, c++11, splay-tree

Some binary tree data structures (such as [Splay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) trees) will re-balance on reads to move recently accessed items toward the root, such that the subsequent look-up time may be reduced.

Are the standard containers (`std::map`, `std::set`) allowed to do this?

At least one concern is thread safety. Previously, I'd thought that as long as you were only doing read-only operations on standard containers, it was safe to do this from multiple threads without introducing mutexes/locks etc. Maybe I need to re-think this?

I know that *typically* red-black trees are used for the standard tree containers, and that these data structures aren't usually modified on reads. But would a hypothetical implementation that did modify be conforming?

My c++-standards-foo needs improvement, but I'm not sure whether the current standard addresses thread-safety for containers. Is this different in `c++0x`?

Comment: Isn't this implementation dependant? doesn't the standard merely define an interface and expected behaviour?

Comment: @Matt H: My thinking is that this would be "observable behaviour" (or however the standard puts it...) - so potentially something that should be addressed in a standardised way. Part of my question is whether it is addressed or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `c++0x` draft:

§23.2.2/1:

> For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, rbegin, rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range, at and, except in associative or unordered associative containers, operator[].

Note that `c++03` does not say anything about multi-threading, but as you say, most implementations use RB-trees, which will not rebalance on a read operation.

Comment: So, if I have it right - since `find` is `const` there is no re-balancing allowed on reads. The fact that `operator[]` is not `const` is just because it's allowed to insert a default item if no match is found. But this is only for `c++0x`...

Comment: @Darren Engwirda- Not exactly. There could still be a rebalance on a read, as long as it was implemented with an atomic commit. It shouldn't make any difference to your code though.

Comment: @Darren: `operator[]` is not on that list because `operator[]` will _insert_ an element into the tree if it is not found. It is a modifying operation.

Comment: @Mankarse: Sorry if I'm not getting it, but if we have `find() const { // etc... }` doesn't the `const` aspect prevent any modification of the underlying tree structure. How could this allow modifications - even if they were thread-safe??

Comment: @Darren - When I said that it could modify the structure I was being pedantic. It is possible that an implementation could use `mutable` members and perform thread-safe rebalancing, but if this did happen, it would have to be in a way that would not change the meaning of your coded. Honestly, I think that it is such an unlikely implementation that the possibility could just be ignored.

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda "_doesn't the const aspect prevent any modification of the underlying tree structure._" It does not. In this context **`const` is a promise that the behaviour of an object will not change.** Since "behaviour" is not formally defined, it is an informal promise. (Within a good specification formalism, you may be able to formally express "behaviour is not changed". But this is entirely outside the formalism that is the C++ language.)

Comment: @Mankarse "_It is possible that an implementation could use mutable_" Possible but not necessary. For you, **the user**, `const` is only a promise the "value" will not change. For you `mutable` is irrelevant. OTOH you would care about what might create a **data race**, if you are doing MT programming.

Answer (score 3):

Read functions on maps etc. are required to have a **const** function defined. Hence you get the guarantee that the object hasn't changed.

This is true both for C++11 ( 23.4.4.1 ) as well as C++03 ( 23.3.1 ).

**23.2.2** of the new C++11 standard may be of special interest here:

> 1. For purposes of avoiding data races (17.6.5.9), implementations shall
>      consider the following functions to be const: begin, end, rbegin,
>      rend, front, back, data, find, lower_bound, upper_bound, equal_range,
>      at and, except in associative or unordered associative containers,
>      operator[].
> 2. Notwithstanding (17.6.5.9), implementations are required
>      to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in
>      different elements in the same sequence, excepting `vector<bool>`, are
>      modified concurrently.

Comment: `const` does not mean what you think it does. See the other comments.

Comment: @curiousguy, I know what it means. But for typical circumstances, the informal promise is all we need.

Comment: A class can implement a cache, and keep its const member functions const (hide the internal state changes), and still be MT-safe (avoid the data races with concurrent calls of const member functions), although this can be tricky.